# Pandas Contain Function Understanding

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand how the Pandas contain function works exactly.

Let's say I have the following:

```
xyz = ['Copyright', 'Microsoft', 'Abc'];
for i in range(0, len(xyz), 1):
     x = z[z.all_data.str.contains(r'.*' + xyz[i] + '.*', regex=True)]
```

This is how I am interpreting the contains function:

> "Search the DataFrame 'z', column called all_data, where the value
>   starts with anything, contains the appropriate index value from xyz,
>   and then ends with anything."

Is my understanding correct?

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
                                              all_data    file_name    
4    * (c) Copyright abc123 Corp. 2015    All Right...   filename.h
```

It's not picking up the word "Copyright" and I'm trying to understand why.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. x = z[z.all_data.str.contains(xyz[i], regex=True)]
2. x = z[z.all_data.str.contains(r'.*' + xyz[i] + '.*', regex=True)]

My code works for other terms, but there is something about that line that does not make it work.

Comment: please post a way that we can actually recreate the dataframe .... (ie 2d list with columns)  ... `z.all_data.str.contains(xyz[i])` alone should work ... i dont know why you need a regex

Comment: i tried it's working fine. not able to reproduce your issue

Comment: However, your code is working for me.

Comment: https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/ImperturbableDisloyalAmoeba

Comment: I will update this post in 5-10 minutes, let me try something really quick.

Comment: You don't have to use a loop. Use `z[z.all_data.str.contains("|".join(xyz)]` to search all keywords in one go.

Comment: I figured out why my code didn't work, it had to do with case sensitivity; however, when I actually run my code against all 1000 files instead of just 5-6, I'd like to experiment with your suggestion for code speed efficiency purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong.

Before:

```
x = z[z.all_data.str.contains(r'.*' + xyz[i] + r'.*', regex=True)]
```

After:

```
x = z[z.all_data.str.contains(r'.*' + xyz[i] + r'.*', case=False,regex=True)]
```

In the `contains` function, case is set to True by default, so I had to change it to false in order to make the function case insensitive. When it's set to True, it is case sensitive.

My DataFrame had "Copyright" in the column but my search criteria was "copyright".

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

at a guess you are **overwriting** `x` for each item ... so if `x` is empty it just means the last `xyz` did not match anything

see this example

```
import pandas
a = [
  ["4    * (c) Copyright abc123 Corp. 2015    All Right...","filename.h"],
  ["4    * (c) noCopy-right abc123 Corp. 2015    All Right...","filename.h"],
  ]
df = pandas.DataFrame(a,columns=['all_data','file'])
print(df)
print("MASK:", df.all_data.str.contains("Copyright"))
print("Matches:",df[df.all_data.str.contains("Copyright")])
```

Comment: What's really weird, is if I use "Copyright" instead of using my loop, it works fine, it's only when I use xyz[i] and it finds some terms but not all.

Comment: `x = "A";` then on next loop `x=None` ... read the first part of my answer

Comment: print X each time you make it ... your code works im sure ... you just overwrite x on the next loop ... all the none means is that it did not match "Abc"

Comment: I am a novice with Python and writing code in general, outside of SQL. Let me play around some more and come back.